# How to use url parameters in angularjs, ui-router and $stateParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angular-ui-router

I have followed the instructions from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing
but cannot get this to work properly.

I have the following:

```
var application = angular.module('application', ['ui.router']);

application.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/test");

$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/test/:param",
        templateUrl: "App/Test.html", 
        controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
            alert($stateParams.param);
        }
    });   

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Without the /:param this works as you would expect - i.e. the ui-view is correctly populated with Test.html.  However, whenever I put the /:param in I get an error.  The error is:

```
GET http://localhost:3880/test/App/Test.html 404 (Not Found)
```

App is the route of my angular stuff and Test.html should have a path of

```
http://localhost:3880/App/Test.html
```

which it does if not trying /:param.  However, when trying /:param you can see that there is an extra /test/ in the path before /App.

Please someone help, as I would like to consume the parameter in the controller once it is correct.

Comment: no answers so far ? @Shumii

Comment: @mavis no - but I used a BaseUrl to get around it.  Then I upgraded angular which removed the need for the BaseUrl.  In short the problem does not exist for me anymore - although I can not be sure enough to give a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You URL for this route should be like this : `http://localhost:3880/test/app` Where app is param.

Comment: Yes, that is the url I am trying to go to.... but I get the error as mentioned which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path for templateUrl. relative url wont work.

```
templateUrl: "/path/to/App/Test.html",
```